# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.' using for loop in Python

Tags: python

My code receives two lines of input and splits those into lists. The result should look like:

**input**

```
4 6
2 4
```

**output**

```
2.0 1.5
```

I'm very new to coding, so my code isn't the most efficient, but here it is:

```
U = list(input().split(" "))
I = list(input().split(" "))
for z in range(len(U)):
    for x in U[z]:
        for y in I[z]:
            R = float(x) / float(y)
            print(round(R, 1), end=" ")
```

When I remove `for x in U[z]:` it works perfectly fine, except it prints every possible result. It also works fine with integers without removing the z loop. The full code for floats, however, prints `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'`. Is there a way to fix this without messing with the code too much?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I just executed exactly that and the output is `2.0 1.5`, no errors. The input I used was `4 6`, then hit Enter, then `2 4` and Enter again

Comment: You don't need to call `list()`, `split()` always returns a list.

Comment: Just some small things.  `.split()` returns a `list`, so there's no reason to use `list()` there.  Also, you can replace the 3 `for` loops with one by using `for x,y in zip(U,I):`.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do. There are many possible solutions to fixing your code but you haven't provided any details about what the intended behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, but only for one digit number. As you iterate on each string value, `14` would generate `'1' '4'`

---

Just keep the outer iteration

```
for z in range(len(U)):
    print(round(float(U[z]) / float(I[z]), 1))
```

Or even better with `zip`

```
U = input(">>").split(" ")
I = input(">>").split(" ")
for x, y in zip(U, I):
    print(round(float(x) / float(y), 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be looping over `U[z]` and `I[z]`. Those are strings, so you're iterating over the characters. And with nested loops, you're making a cross-product of all the characters in each list element.

Just use one loop over the indexes.

```
U = input().split(" ")
I = input().split(" ")
for z in range(len(U)):
    x = U[z]
    y = I[z]
    R = float(x) / float(y)
    print(round(R, 1), end=" ")
```

Or use `zip()` to loop over the two lists in parallel:

```
for x, y in zip(U, I):
    R = float(x) / float(y)
    print(round(R, 1), end=" ")
```